# PHP: getting only 1 result from XML collection

Tags: php, xml, loops, foreach

I'm trying to read an XML file with PHP but I'm only getting the first result and can't figure out why.

XML structure:

```
<main>
  <data>
   <record>
    <column name="title">Some title here</column>
   </record>
   <record>
    <column name="title">Some second title here</column>
   </record>
  </data>
</main>
```

Pretty basic. This is the code I'm using to getting the results:

```
foreach($XML->data->record as $product) {
  $title = mysql_real_escape_string($product->title);
}
```

But this only gives an empty string so I guess I'm looking at the wrong path. The code below does work, but only gives me the first record and not the other records in the XML file.

```
foreach($XML->data as $product) {
  $title = mysql_real_escape_string($product->record->title);
}
```

The answer is probably easy, but I can't figure it out. Hope someone is willing to help :)

Comment: How are you loading the xml file to $XML in your code ?

Comment: you **SURE** It's an empty string, not boolean false? you have to be connected to mysql to use that function, and the entire `mysql_*()` function-set is obsolete anyways. You shouldn't be using it in any new code.

Answer (score 2):

`title` is the value of the `name` **attribute** of the `<column>` node.
You can't access it the way you do it.

To access the `<column>` node:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assume XML in $x

foreach ($xml->data->record as $product) {
    echo $product->column;
}
```

Output:

```
Some title here
Some second title here
```

see it working: https://eval.in/506519

If there are many columns under each record...

```
<record>
    <column name="title">Some title here</column>
    <column name="car">BMW</column>
    <column name="color">red</column>
</record>
```

... and you want to list all, you need a second loop:

```
foreach ($xml->data->record as $product) {  // same as above
    foreach ($product->column as $column) { // iterate all column 
        echo $column['name'] . ": " . $column . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
title: Some title here
car: BMW
color: red
```

see it working: https://eval.in/506521

In case you want only `<column>` nodes with `name = "title"`, check with `if`:

```
foreach ($xml->data->record as $product) {  // same as above
    foreach ($product->column as $column) { // iterate all column 
        if ($column['name'] == "title") echo $column . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

see it working: https://eval.in/506523

And be aware that there is a different way to get all `<column>` with `name = "title"` with `xpath`:

```
$titles = $xml->xpath("//column[@name = 'title']");
foreach ($titles as $title)
    echo $title . PHP_EOL;
```

see it in action: https://eval.in/506531

For an explanation of the `xpath` syntax, look at [Using xPath to access values of simpleXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25025120/using-xpath-to-access-values-of-simplexml) and zillion others.

and BTW: as said in comments, don't use `mysql_`...

Comment: It works with a second loop and check on column name, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but looks ok. Load the xml file / string into DOMDocument and get all the `column` nodes and iterate through them

```
$dom=new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML( $strxml );
/*
    or
    --
$dom->load( $xmlfile );
*/

$col=$dom->getElementsByTagName('column');
foreach( $col as $node ){
    echo $node->tagName.' '.$node->getAttribute('title').' '.$node->nodeValue;
}
```